# React Testing Library won't see my checkbox as clicked

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I'm calling this click on this checkbox, and RTL is not reading it as checked.

```
configure({ testIdAttribute: 'data-cy' })

const selectAllBeef = await screen.findByTestId(
  `${TEST_ID.MULTI_SELECT_ACCORDION_ITEM}_971520`
)
fireEvent.click(selectAllBeef)
await waitFor(() => {
  expect(selectAllBeef).toBeChecked()
})
```

I haven't included the component code, but these facts should be enough:

Test output: (it is indeed not checked)

```
Received element is not checked:
  <input class="_5s76jf9 _1d1jhrro8 _1d1jhrr2u" data-cy="MULTI_SELECT_ACCORDION_ITEM_971520" id="971520" type="checkbox" />
```

When I try in the browser, using the same selector as in RTL, the correct element is indeed clicked and the box is checked. I can see it in the UI and `checked` is added to the html in the devtools elements panel:

```
checkbox = $('[data-cy="MULTI_SELECT_ACCORDION_ITEM_971520"]')
checkbox.click()
```

I've tried, in the test, `selectBeef.click()`, and `userEvent.click(selectBeef)`, and `fireEvent.click(selectBeef)`. I've tried wrapping each of these in `act`, with and without `await`, and I've also tried wrapping the assertion in `waitFor`.

I've tried `render`ing the component that includes all the various checkboxes (which includes its own state handling of the checkboxes), as well as rendering the page this component is contained in. Which is to say it shouldn't be any issue with the state or controlled-ness of the checkbox since the state/controlled-ness is "beneath" the components RTL is rendering.

Nothing works. What am I missing?

Comment: The way you check the checkbox and then check for its state should be working fine. Maybe you have other side-effect that influences the checkbox when you click it.